# How to draw cube via LWJGL?

Tags: java, kotlin, lwjgl

I'm trying to draw cube in OpenGL (LWJGL) as I did it with quad (and it worked), but it draws only a flashing yellow square. In Internet, I've found only some examples with vertexes parts and tried to make smth from it, but it was't successfull. Where am I wrong?

```
    ...
    private fun drawCube(size: Float){
        val half = size / 2

        GL11.glTranslatef(0f,0.0f,-7f)
        GL11.glRotatef(45f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f)
        GL11.glColor3f(0.5f,0.5f,1.0f)

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS)

        GL11.glColor3f(0f,0f,1f)
        GL11.glVertex3f(-half, -half, -half)
        GL11.glVertex3f(-half, size - half, -half)
        GL11.glVertex3f(size - half, size-half, -half)
        GL11.glVertex3f(size - half, -half, -half)
        // the same for other 5
        GL11.glEnd()
    }

    private fun loop(){
        GL.createCapabilities()
        while (GLFW.glfwWindowShouldClose(window).toInt() == GLFW.GLFW_FALSE) {
            GL11.glClearColor(colorMain[0], colorMain[1], colorMain[2], 0.0f)
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
            render()
            GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(window)
            GLFW.glfwPollEvents()
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: Kind of need to see all six sides to see where the error is. Also, it might be easier to read your code if you just use `half` instead of `size - half`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 sorry, [here it is](https://pastebin.com/2TjRz07M)